# Need help to rig this over-the-top flipper lid

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm trying to rig a flipping lid for my delivery robot project.

[image]
[image]

As you can see on the pictures above there are two pivoting arms, and two guiding elements that make the lid slide along them on a set of rails.

[image]

I recently got into rigging, however I haven't been able to make this one work.

Answer (score 3):

A cheap way to do it would be to create these 3 bones, the bone 2 (the lid) being the child of 1 (the arm) and the bone 3 being independent (you'll parent the sliding piece to this last bone). Create a first keyframe:

[image]

Rotate bone 1 90° and rotate bone 2 and 3 so that they correctly place the lid and sliding piece:

[image]

Rotate bone 1 again until the lid is completely open, again rotate bone 2 and 3:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clear demonstration moonboots !